# How to define R functions with mutate_(), paste(), and varnames

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a function to optimize my code.
I have tibbles in the following format. I want to add a 5th and final column that is a  titled "AGG_range."

```
>data.temp0 
  AGG_median AGG_mean AGG_min AGG_max
       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       38       40.7      29      52
2       49       49        21      83
3       30       39        10      75
4       38       38.9      13      59
5       63.5     57.4      15      82
6       32       33        21      50
7       39       40.5      14      75
```

I have tried using 
mutate(!!varname =  paste(!!varname2,!!varname3,sep="-") 
 AND
mutate_(somename = paste(varname2,varna,sep="-"))

However the results I am getting is not what I want.

A simple example of what I am doing is the following:

```
myfuntemp  = function(chr_temp){
  chr_temp.range = chr_temp %>%
    paste("range",sep="_")
  chr_temp.min = chr_temp %>%
    paste("min",sep="_")
  chr_temp.max = chr_temp %>%
    paste("max",sep="_")
  dat_temp = data.temp0 %>%
    mutate_(chr_temp.range = paste("(",as.character(chr_temp.min),"-",
                                   as.character(chr_temp.max),")",sep="")) %>%

    rename (!!chr_temp.range:= chr_temp.range)

  return(dat_temp)

}
```

The following is what I get (actual output)

```
>myfuntemp('AGG')

  AGG_median AGG_mean AGG_min AGG_max AGG_range
       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1       38       40.7      29      52       -23
2       49       49        21      83       -62
3       30       39        10      75       -65
4       38       38.9      13      59       -46
5       63.5     57.4      15      82       -67
6       32       33        21      50       -29
7       39       40.5      14      75       -61
```

However, the following is what I want (expected output)

```
  AGG_median AGG_mean AGG_min AGG_max AGG_range 
       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    
1       38       40.7      29      52 (29-52)  
2       49       49        21      83 (21-83)  
3       30       39        10      75 (10-75)  
4       38       38.9      13      59 (13-59)  
5       63.5     57.4      15      82 (15-82)  
6       32       33        21      50 (21-50)  
7       39       40.5      14      75 (14-75)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(min=sample(c(1:5),5,T),mean=sample(c(10:20),5,T),max=sample(c(25:35),5,T))

myfun <- function(data){
  data <- data %>% mutate(range=paste0('(',min,' - ',max,')'))
  return(data)
}

myfun(df)

  min mean max    range
1   3   14  35 (3 - 35)
2   3   13  29 (3 - 29)
3   2   15  27 (2 - 27)
4   2   18  35 (2 - 35)
5   3   19  33 (3 - 33)
```

**UPDATE**
This function will rename the variables as well as creating the range variable.

```r
myfun2 <- function(data,newname='AGG'){
  data <- data %>% mutate(range=paste0('(',min,' - ',max,')'))
  names(data) <- paste0(newname,'_',names(data))
  return(data)
}

myfun2(df,'AGG')
  AGG_min AGG_mean AGG_max AGG_range
1       3       14      35  (3 - 35)
2       3       13      29  (3 - 29)
3       2       15      27  (2 - 27)
4       2       18      35  (2 - 35)
5       3       19      33  (3 - 33)
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you.  However, what I really want to do is call "min" and "max" as unique variable names, as it is in my example function. My question may not be the most efficient way, but I'm curious as to what the solution is.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the post. Is this closer to what you are looking for? Like you said, it is unclear since your original data closely matches your expected output.

Comment: This actually is a much simpler solution, thank you.  I was over complicating it. I am still trying to learn how to call variable names in functions like this.  Do you know how I could have made my code work?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your code. But it looks like your function is calling `data.temp0` which isn't defined inside it. And `chr_temp %>%
    paste("range",sep="_")` will not work as a `dplyr` call.